# Trigger jQuery event and know if and Checkbox in list/array is checked

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, checkbox, eventtrigger

The code below is a cut down version of the page, but you see that it will iterate through a list and produce a checkbox for each item in the list.

What I want to know:

1. How do I trigger a jQuery event when ANY of the checkboxes are clicked (either making them checked or unchecked)?
2. What jQuery code do I need to then look at the list of checkboxes produced by the below code and then make a button (e.g. with id="DeleteSelected" ) visible if any are checked, or hide the button if they are all unchecked?

> ```
> <s:form action="manageQuestions" >
>     <s:iterator value="questions" id="currentQuestion">
>         <s:checkbox name="questionCheck" id="ch-%{id}" value="selected" fieldValue="%{id}"/>
>     </s:iterator>
> </s:form>
> ```

I'm such a jQuery dunce that I know that I need to put:

```
<script>

</script>
```

there at the end but that's all I know.  I don't know if I need to put:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //something here
}
```

or if I don't need the document ready etc. at all.

Comment: Show the final markup as on the page as that will help us help you better/quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/AfEriqe/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
  $(checkboxes).on('change', function() {
    console.log('checkbox changed');
    if($(checkboxes).is(':checked')) {
      console.log('at least one checked');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - I'm avoiding saying thanks as is suggested with the placeholder for comment text ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I wish to add to Vlad's answer, to change the css class of the element that I wanted to show/hide, the condition check was extended to:

```
if($(checkboxes).is(':checked')) {
    $("#deleteSelected").attr('class', 'visible');
} else {
    $("#deleteSelected").attr('class', 'hidden');
}
```

where 'deleteSelected' is the id of the element to show/hide